# GMAT 3 overlapping sets problem

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having way too much trouble getting to the solution of this one problem:

In a certain school with 50 students, the school offers economics, mathematics, and
statistics in the first semester and finance in the second semester. 40 students take
economics, 30 students take mathematics, and 45 students take either economics or
mathematics. 15 students do not take statistics. No students take exactly one course
from these three classes in the first semester. If the finance class’s prerequisite courses
are mathematics, economics, and statistics, how many students are eligible to take
finance? Circle your choice below:
(A) 0
(B) 5
(C) 10
(D) 15 (The right answer)
(E) 20

Applying 2 set theory between mathematics and economics I've gotten to the point that students studying both economics and mathematics are 25. I cannot proceed further than that; can someone lend me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The key piece of information is the fact that *no student takes exactly one course*.  So the 15 who did not take statistics must be in both math and economics. You've figured out that the total number in both math and economics is 25, so the remaining 10 must be in statistics. These are the 10 who are in all three courses.</strike>

Try drawing a Venn Diagram. For each class, their exclusive region will be zero. There must be 35 in the stats circle, 40 in the econ circle, and 30 in the math circle. If you put 15 in the 3-way intersection, 5 in the math-stats intersection, 10 in the math-econ intersection, 15 in the stats-econ intersection, and 5 completely outside, then the solution works.

Comment: The solution to the problem is 15 as I just read on the end of the sheet, but it doesn't show how to do it. I think this piece of data _45 students take either economics or mathematics_ can be relevant but I don't know how to interpret the one you mentioned

Comment: The question says "No students take exactly one course from these three classes in the first semester" so it means that each student takes either two or three classes. I don't think 15 is correct, unless there is some more information, you can use the inclusion-exclusion principle to show there are 10 students in the intersection of all three classes.

Comment: Wait. I figured out my mistake, I've edited my post.